# VBA and concatenate function

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation, formula

I'm actually looking to optimize my existing concatenate formula that I use to configure a bunch of controller (networking)

I have Sheet1 where I enter all the details requiered from A2 to E2
I have Sheet2 where that produce the overall concatenate, that include the valude from Sheet1.A2 and include some command, here is the concatenate formula:

=CONCATENATE("ap ",Imported_Data!B2,CHAR(10)," ip enable ",CHAR(10)," ip mode static ",CHAR(10)," ip addr ",Imported_Data!A2," ",Imported_Data!L$2," gateway ",Imported_Data!L$3,CHAR(10)," ip name-server ",Imported_Data!L$4," ",Imported_Data!L$5,CHAR(10)," devname ",Imported_Data!C2,CHAR(10)," description ",CHAR(147),Imported_Data!D2,CHAR(147),CHAR(10)," location ",CHAR(147),Imported_Data!E2,CHAR(147),CHAR(10)," end")

and the result below:

```
"ap 00:00:00:00:00:00
 ip enable 
 ip mode static 
 ip addr 1.1.1.1 255.255.0.0 gateway 172.27.1.1
 ip name-server 4.2.2.1 4.2.2.2
 devname name
 description “Description“
 location “location“
 end"
```

in order to have it accepted on the controller is to manipulate the result, copy the concatenate result into notepad++, remove the "" that added from the concatenate formula, and replace the CHAR(147) by "" ( that the only way I've found to have it working)

what I would like to have in VBA is a filter that will:

1) remove the "" at the begining and end of the block of concatenate
2) replace the `` with "" at the description and location

end result should be:

```
ap 00:00:00:00:00:00
 ip enable 
 ip mode static 
 ip addr 1.1.1.1 255.255.0.0 gateway 172.27.1.1
 ip name-server 4.2.2.1 4.2.2.2
 devname name
 description "Description"
 location "location"
 end
```

any suggestion/advise?

Comment: CHAR(147) shall be replaced by CHAR(34) if you need double quotes (") as I am seeing in the desired behavior.

Comment: then if I replace CHAR(147) by CHAR(34) I cannot use the search and replace and remove the quote added at the beginning and end of the block which is an issue has I'm running arround 200 block each time

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I have posted one possible approach. It is more of a work around which I cannot post as comment due to length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way which you should check if it suits your purpose.

First edit formula to replace CHAR(147) to CHAR(34) like below:

`=CONCATENATE("ap ",Imported_Data!B2,CHAR(10)," ip enable ",CHAR(10)," ip mode static ",CHAR(10)," ip addr ",Imported_Data!A2," ",Imported_Data!L$2," gateway ",Imported_Data!L$3,CHAR(10)," ip name-server ",Imported_Data!L$4," ",Imported_Data!L$5,CHAR(10)," devname ",Imported_Data!C2,CHAR(10)," description ",CHAR(34),Imported_Data!D2,CHAR(34),CHAR(10)," location ",CHAR(34),Imported_Data!E2,CHAR(34),CHAR(10)," end")`

And then paste below code to VBE. Make sure to update cell references to suit.

```
Public Sub CopyConcatToNotepad()
    Dim objDataObj As Object
    Dim strFormula

    strFormula = Split(Sheets(2).Range("A1").Value, vbCrLf) 'Write correct cell reference for CONCATENATE formula cell!
    Dim strOut As String
    strOut = Join(strFormula, vbCrLf)

    'This is ClsID of MSFORMS Data Object
    Set objDataObj = CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    objDataObj.SetText strOut, 1
    objDataObj.PutInClipboard

    Set objDataObj = Nothing
End Sub
```

Then run this code to copy text as desired to clipboard. If you will do CTRL+V in Notepad++ then it will give desired results!

**EDIT:** Revised code to incorporate requirements.

```
Public Sub CopyConcatToNotepadSelCells()
Dim objDataObj As Object
Dim rG As Range
Dim strFormula
Dim strOut As String

'Loop through all selected cells and build concat string
For Each rG In Selection
    strFormula = Split(rG.Value, vbCrLf)
    If Len(strOut) = 0 Then
        strOut = Join(strFormula, vbCrLf)
    Else
        strOut = strOut & vbCrLf & Join(strFormula, vbCrLf)
    End If
Next rG

'This is ClsID of MSFORMS Data Object
Set objDataObj = CreateObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
objDataObj.SetText strOut, 1
objDataObj.PutInClipboard

Set objDataObj = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: This work like a charm, how can I carry and copy all the CONCATENATE where we have value from Sheet1? 

at present it copy only A1, best would be to have a function to gather how many entry we have on Sheet1 column A1 for example, and copy the exact number of cell from Sheet2

Comment: @QuentinD Do you mean you have CONCATENATE formula copied down several cells and you need to copy in one go?

Comment: @QuentinD This is how I will do it. See the revised code `CopyConcatToNotepadSelCells` under EDIT section of my post.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! amazing @Shrivallabha.redij